# What happens after a draw

Tags: love-letter

In love letter there are some situations, when players have to compare their hands (after using the Baron card or at the end of the round).

What happens if there is a draw?

**Situation 1:**

> A: House maiden (4), Baron(3), B: House maiden(4) , C: Priest(2)
>
> A plays baron on B, both have House maiden.

What happens? Also what happens, if there is no player C?

**Situation 2:**

> End of the round
>
> A: House maiden (4), B: House maiden(4) , C: Priest(2)

Who wins this round? Both A and B? C? No one?

**Edit**

the answer in [How can we determine the winner in Love Letter if the last two players tie and have the same value of cards discarded?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23924/how-can-we-determine-the-winner-in-love-letter-if-the-last-two-players-tie-and-h) answered only for the second situation. the first one is answered by Ken.

Comment: Related https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23924/how-can-we-determine-the-winner-in-love-letter-if-the-last-two-players-tie-and-h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In situation 1 nothing will happen. This is explicitly covered in the rules under the expanded text for the Baron card (page 10 in [the Premium edition rulebook](http://alderac.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Love-Letter-Premium_Rulebook.pdf)).

Situation 2 is also covered in the rules. On page 6 of the Premium edition rules linked above:

> In case of a tie, players add the numbers on the cards in their discard pile. The highest total wins. If there is still a tie, then all tied
>   players are considered to have won the round.